# Mongo driver for C#: Deserialization of FindAs method

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

The method definition is like below

```
Db.FindAs<TDocument>(QueryDocument)
```

Then when the TDocument type is set to a struct type

```
Db.FindAs<AStruct>(query);
```

I got an exception saying that the document cannot be deserialized to Astruct.
But if I edit the Astruct and alter 'struct' to 'class' , everything works very well.

Whether the red rectangle indicates something underlying about this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In C# structs are value types and the error is saying that the serializer does not know how to serialize value classes.